# how to get the last value from mysql and increment with php

Tags: php, mysql

i have a user database and i have to assign a user id for them for example AA01
AND after insert 1 person into database i have to insert another person with user id AA02 AND i have increment it and so on.
what i have already tried is

```
$sql_user_id=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(user_id) FROM `users` desc LIMIT 1");
$new_array = explode('AA',$sql_user_id);
$number=$new_array[1];
$newnumber=$number+1;
```

and i am getting wrong with result `Resource id #5`

Answer (score 1):

You have to fetch the query results before you can use them.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT MAX(user_id) AS maxId FROM `users` desc LIMIT 1");
$sql_user_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$new_array = explode('AA',$sql_user_id['maxId']);
$number=$new_array[1];
$newnumber=$number+1;
```

FYI, I added an alias to your query as it makes referencing a value returned from a function much easier to do.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query()` returns a resource, not a value you can operate directly. You have to fetch the value from this resource first:

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT MAX(`user_id`) FROM `users`');
$val = mysql_fetch_row($res);
$new_array = explode('AA', $val[0]);
...
```

Also, notice that `MAX()` causes an implicit grouping to happen. So there is no order, and there is only one result. Specifying any of this in your query is futile.

In addition, notice that, since `user_id` is aparently a text, it might not work as expected. When sorting text, `2` comes after `10`. You may need to use a different reference to fetch the latest `user_id`. If you can help it, don't use text to index your records.